# Google Identity Toolkit offline scope for Android apps

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I would like to retrieve an offline access token for a web back-end as described here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens

That page gives the following scope as an example:

oauth2:server:client_id:***[client id]***:api_scope:***[scopes]***

After replacing the client id and scopes with my own, I was able to use this successfully with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(), but I have been unable to make it work with the Google Identity Toolkit for Android.  It seems you cannot properly format the scope by using [GitkitClientBuilder.addScopes()](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/reference/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClientBuilder.html#addScopes(com.google.identitytoolkit.IdProvider,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), since the toolkit adds its own scopes on top of yours.

Is it possible to get an offline access token using the Google Identity Toolkit for Android?